# iOS, layout position depending on screen size issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xib

I am trying to optimize how the app looks for different screen sizes and whatever I do, somehow, in the `.xib` I am not able to prevent some layout misplacements from happening when I switch from 6splus->6s->5 iPhone simulators. I am trying to fix the space from my labels to image view (which serves as a background) and then scale the fonts depending on the device. Although I set up constraints, they are somehow messed up and not enforced from one screen size to another.

6splus looks like this:

[image]

Here you can see that the positioning is completely wrong from the right side even though right spacing is set up in the `.xib`

Then, going to 6s:

[image]

Looks relatively fine (since I optimized it for 6s initially)

Notice how it shifted from right to left. I definitely want to prevent it from happening.

Then, iPhone 5:

[image]

Completely shifted to left. Also somehow spacing between the red color day of the week and day number increased. This is the second thing I really-really want to avoid from happening. Third thing is the label on the left bottom: it is shifting a bit, and I will need to place two more labels there, so it is very crucial to avoid it shifting too.

Here is the screenshot of my `.xib` with constraints:

[image]

The `.xib` is the customizable `UITableViewCell` that I am using in `UITableView`.

The following images show the constraints by label:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

UIImageView (Background) constraints:

[image]

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which item is constrained to the leading or trailing edge/margin?  The 'Event Day Num' is only constrained to the center of the location and week day labels.  Is one of these constrained to the leading/trailing?

Comment: I updated the question with the additional screenshots, please, have a look. Also, for the bottom left label I want to avoid shifting too.

Comment: I am also changing fonts dynamically, but it does not matter here because the same things happen even if I set them for all of the screen sizes.

Comment: I think your constraints are way too complex. I set up a quick test for myself;  The first thing I did was create a UIView to the right of the image view and then put the day/date and bottom labels in that.  I set the left hand image to be 3/4 of the content view cell and then constrained the UIView with the labels to the right of the image and the trailing edge of their containing view.  Then I set constraints for the labels within the content view

Comment: Hi, i think u can try to put each group of things into a UIView, then u layout that view first, it would be very easy to layout a bunch of things at once since your group of things is pinned to your UIView

Comment: Nice idea, I like it, but I tried and it does not solve the issues. Same things happen.

Comment: I have this UIView with labels on the right. I set up the constraints relative to the UIImageView which is the background and Xcode just does whatever it likes without considering these constraints shifting things to the left/right.

Comment: I am trying now to dynamically (depending on the screen width) change margin to the right of the UIView with labels, maybe this will help...

Answer (score 0):

So, what I end up doing is creating 4 outlets for 4 different constraints:

```
1. @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *eventNameBottomMargin;
2. @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *eventNameLeftMargin;
3. @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *bottomMarginConstraint;
4. @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *rightMarginConstraint;
```

Constraints 1,2 are for the `UILabel` at the bottom left; constraints 3,4 are for the `UILabels` at the right: using `Tj3n`'s advice I put them in a `UIView`, so then 3,4 are constraints of the `UIView` in relation to the background `UIImageView`.

Then I changed the values of the constraints in the code depending on the device width:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
[super awakeFromNib];
CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
NSNumber *screenWidth = @(screenRect.size.width);
[self setFontsOnDeviceWithScreenWidth:screenWidth];

int rightMargin = 15;
int bottomMargin = -105;
int nameLeftMargin = 55;
int nameBottomMargin = -33;

if (screenWidth.intValue == 320) {
    // iPhone 5 screenWidth = "320"
    rightMargin = 5;
    bottomMargin = -105;
    nameLeftMargin = 50;
    nameBottomMargin = -36;
} else if(screenWidth.intValue == 375) {
    // iPhone 6s
    rightMargin = 15;
    bottomMargin = -105;
    nameLeftMargin = 80;
    nameBottomMargin = -30;
} else if(screenWidth.intValue == 414) {
    // iPhone 6s Plus
    rightMargin = 35;
    bottomMargin = -108;
    nameLeftMargin = 100;
    nameBottomMargin = -30;
}
self.rightMarginConstraint.constant = rightMargin;
self.bottomMarginConstraint.constant = bottomMargin;
self.eventNameLeftMargin.constant = nameLeftMargin;
self.eventNameBottomMargin.constant = nameBottomMargin;
}
```

I do not think it is the best solution for the problem, but it is working perfectly. There should be a way to just specify constraints and then resizing would go automatically, so if someone knows, please, share further thoughts.